# Angular 2 Integration Testing (Unit Test Style)

Tags: angular, jasmine, integration-testing, karma-jasmine

Is it possible to test an angular app with its testing framework (primarily designed for unit testing) against a real backend?

Let's say E2E Testing with Protractor is not an option for me, but still i want to do some integration tests within my Unit Test Environment with Karma. I really have trouble finding examples or even a statement if it's possible or not using Jasmine and the testing libs of angular 2.

I know, that this isn't supposed to be best (or even just a good) practice, but that's not the topic here. Everywhere i searched (and i searched a lot) i'll find approaches with `MockBackend` and the statement "We don't want to hit the real backend...." but nowhere is said if it's possible at all and if yes, how.

I tried several approaches ("normal" vs. async tests), spying on the service methods from within my Component Testbed, calling the Service functions (which return an Observable, after a backend request is fired) directly and trying to continue from within the subscribe function, but my tests don't care. Those parts are always skipped.

Imagine something like this:

```
fit('should show an error if the email entered is invalid', async(() => {
    let accService: any = fixture.debugElement.injector.get(AccountService);
    let accSpy: jasmine.Spy = spyOn(accService, 'isExistingEmail').and.callThrough();
    let checkEmailSpy: jasmine.Spy = spyOn(comp, 'checkEmail').and.callThrough();

    expect(checkEmailSpy).not.toHaveBeenCalled();
    emailInput.triggerEventHandler('blur', null);
    fixture.detectChanges();
    expect(checkEmailSpy).toHaveBeenCalled();
    expect(comp.emailInvalid).toBe(true);

    ...

    accService.isExistingEmail('abcdefg').subscribe((res) => {
        expect(accSpy).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(7);
    }, (err) => {
        expect(accSpy).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(7);
    });

    accSpy.calls.mostRecent().returnValue.subscribe((res) => {
        expect(accSpy).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(7);
    }, (err) => {
        expect(accSpy).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(7);
    });

    ...

}));
```

Now in the first part of this test, the `blur` event will trigger the components `checkEmail` function, which will call something in my service (which then will ask another service for the actual backend call and return this observable). If the email is wrong, `false` will be returned to the components function and `comp.emailInvalid` is set to true).

The `toHaveBeenCalled` tests in this part actually pass, but the `expect(comp.emailInvalid).toBe(true)` part doesn't.

When i run the test and open up the debug tab in Karma-Chrome-Launcher i actually see the real requests to the backend with the right response. So the requests are actually done, but i just don't get these responses back to my test.

In the bottom part of this example, i tried to use the service directly to get my response. So i tried to `mock` the actual program flow to retrieve the backend responses. But in these cases, the `expect` calls are never fired. However, if i put some `console.log` statements in the real service i see that they are called two times (from the blur event and from the direct call `accService.isExistingEmail`).

Any hints how i could handle this would be so much appreciated.

The main reason for this is, that we don't want to setup huge mock files which simulate the backend responses.

### Edit:

If there isn't any solution for this and i still don't want to use UI Tests like E2E with protractor, how would i do integration testing?

Comment: I understand the motivation under this but I don't think you should test a webservice or an API with a unit test, just because it is that, a unit test. You should test your webservice in a e2e test, or integration test.

Comment: Also, unit tests are supposed and intended to be fast. Hitting a web service are gonna make those quite slower.

Comment: And for finishing, the disadvantages of hitting a web-service instead of mocking the object signatures (sometimes hard and boring) are much more. I will put all of these into an answer and upvote or accept just if you like.

Comment: @lexith, I won't repeat all the same what Jorge have already said, will just add something. To test against real service you don't need to spy on anything. Integration tests should just generate request and then assert result. They don't care about what happens between those points - that's not their business. This means that you don't actually need any spies. Try to remove them and see if it works. Also, make sure that test does not times out while it makes all necessary calls, because usually asynchronous unit tests have pretty small default timeouts, like 2 secs.

Comment: Thank you for your comments so far. I know that there are several downsides in the way i want to do this, but as i said, at least we want to try and compare it in terms of development time, execution time etc. @AlexanderLeonov i will try to remove the spies, but since `and.callThrough` is exactly for this purpose (spying on something but making sure it executes as it would normally) i don't think it will make a difference. The hint with the default timeout is good, but i already set it to 10 seconds, so this shouldnt be the issue.

Comment: @Jorge what would be the alternative in using e2e with protractor and unit tests with karma? How would i setup integration tests which aren't UI Tests?

Comment: @lexith, when I was speaking about spies I meant that you didn't need them regardless of their guiltiness. :) I mean, even if you assert that something was successfully called in the chain, but overall it did not return proper result - nothing changes: the test has failed. This is why integration test should not care about anything else but input (command/query) and output (result). You have unit tests with mocks for making sure that something calls another something with certain parameters.

Comment: @lexith, also, make sure that the environment which you're testing in allows making such calls at all. For example, if the call goes to some localhost's rest service by default then make sure it is up and running on the server where you're actually running your tests. Also, take into account firewalls and other things that can influence making calls.