# How to test the whole process from UI layer to database entry in Angular using unit testing or other testing?

Tags: angular, unit-testing

Here I am checking the validation and input values which was send through the form when I clicked the submit button. Up to this my testing is fine but how to send the input values to the database to check whether the whole process is working properly or not. Is it possible the to do with unit testing? Or any other testing?

```ts
describe('CategoryAddComponent', () => {

    let fixture: ComponentFixture<CategoryAddComponent>;
    let component: CategoryAddComponent;
    let categoryService: CategoryService;
    let de: DebugElement;
    let el: HTMLElement;

    beforeEach(async(() => {

        TestBed.configureTestingModule({
            imports: [ReactiveFormsModule, FormsModule, SharedModule, UiSwitchModule, AlertModule.forRoot(), NgaModule, HttpModule, RouterModule.forRoot([]), CookieModule.forRoot()],

            declarations: [CategoryAddComponent],
            //providers:    [ {provide: CustomerService, useValue: customerServiceStub }, CustomerService,CustomerModelService,AppState,BaThemeConfigProvider ]
            providers: [{ provide: APP_BASE_HREF, useValue: '/' }, CategoryService, CategoryModelService, AppState, BaThemeConfigProvider],
        })
            .compileComponents();

    }));

    beforeEach(() => {

        fixture = TestBed.createComponent(CategoryAddComponent);
        component = fixture.componentInstance;
        de = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('h1'));
        el = de.nativeElement;
        categoryService = TestBed.get(CategoryService);

        component.ngOnInit();
        fixture.detectChanges();

    });


    it('form invalid when empty', () => {
        expect(component.form.valid).toBeFalsy();
    });

    it('submitting the form by clicking the button', () => {

        expect(component.form.valid).toBeFalsy();
        component.form.controls['code'].setValue('1234');

        expect(component.form.controls['code'].valid).toBeTruthy();

        spyOn(component, 'onSubmit');
        de = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('#buto'));
        el = de.nativeElement;

        el.click();
        fixture.detectChanges();

        expect(component.onSubmit).toHaveBeenCalledWith({
            code: '1234',
            name:new Object(),
            status: true,
            remarks: ''
        });

    });

    it('dom ', () => {
        fixture.detectChanges();
        expect(el.textContent).toContain('Add Category');
    });


 });
```

Comment: 1. You shouldn't be spying on methods of the unit under test, see what the *service* gets called with instead. Mocking it out was a good idea, not sure why you've commented that out - what you have isn't really a unit test any more. 2. Then you test the service, so that given the expected values it makes the right call to the API. 3. End to end tests, rather than unit tests, driving the app from a browser using e.g. Protractor let you test the whole system works together.

Comment: @jonrsharpe there are maaaaany reason why you would spy upon methods of a unit under a test. And his way (accessing DOM with the help of a `DebugElement` and then spying on the method that should be called by a button press) is absolutely valid. In another test, which should test the `onSubmit` function, yea there you should spy on a service method probably...

Comment: @lexith I'd consider this a smell in testing an Angular component. The thing you *actually care about* is that the service gets called with the right data when the button is clicked. If you make minor implementation changes like renaming the method or passing the data from a property instead of the template, you shouldn't need to change the tests. I'd call the whole component the unit, and not test at the template-class boundary, otherwise you end up coupling to implementation.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Nope sorry, can't agree. Every function, every property, every event called or received in a component, every button and all those other things in your component are units. You test the the smallest piece of unit in a unit test. The service call is just an implementation you want to test, but that doesn't mean that the whole component (or in this case the button click) just does this one call.

Comment: That's basically the reason why you have a `describe` block which groups single unit tests regarding a certain component / module together, but still every `it` block should only test a single purpose. `it('should emit a click event correctly on button press', ...);`, `it('should call my service after onSubmit is called', ...);`, `it('should change stuff after the service is called`, ...);` and so on.

Comment: @lexith well you're entitled to your opinion. Note that I'm not saying that you should only have one spec or that the component, or the click, only does one thing. I'm just saying that *I would treat the template-class interaction as implementation detail, not interface*. I would write `it('should call service with data when button is clicked', ...);`, `it('should change stuff when button is clicked', ...);`, and so on, testing through the `@Input`s, `@Output`s and the rendered HTML. In my experience this leads to more useful tests that don't change with every refactor.

Comment: Can I do something like this to check whether data is inserted or not in the database?? 'component.onSubmit.call(categoryService.add(component.form.value).subscribe(result=>{
            console.log(result);
        }))'

Comment: @Kanaz that *doesn't* check the data as, unless you're calling the real API (which, I think we can all agree, wouldn't be a unit test). Again, use end to end testing: start up the API and app server; connect to a real database; fill in and submit the form through the browser; then check that the additional category is displayed on a page somewhere. This simulates how a user will interact with the app.

Comment: @jonrsharpe okay then i will try out the e2e testing.

Comment: It would be actually super helpful if there were a possibilty to do integration tests in an angular environment with a unit test-like structure, but sadly it's not possible. @jonrsharpe of course it's primarily opinion based, but i don't see why you would do it like that. the button click does not call the service. The function that is invoked on button click calls the service. Clearly two different tasks that can change over time and should be treated seperately.

Comment: @lexith it is possible (there's nothing to stop you *not* mocking out Http and making your own calls to the API from the tests), but not that helpful (you could put the whole app in the testbed if you want, but it would be very slow). And I've told you why we do it like that (test behaviour, not implementation).

Comment: @jonrsharpe nope, will not work. You can make the requests yourself, they will be executed in the browser, but you will not get the response back in your test to work with it. If you think it's possible you can answer this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40715800/angular-2-integration-testing-unit-test-style i asked it some time ago ;)

Comment: @lexith ah interesting, thanks!

Comment: @jonrsharpe if you'll ever find a solution, feel free to answer :)

Comment: @jonrsharpe Is it possible to use the headless browser for the e2e testing?

Comment: @Kanaz yes, of course. I'd recommend headless Chrome rather than PhantomJS if at all possible, haven't tried the other options myself.